# If both roots of the Quadratic Equation are similar then prove that

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, quadratics

If both roots of the equation $(a-b)x^2+(b-c)x+(c-a)=0$ are equal, prove that $2a=b+c$.

> **Things should be known:**
>
> - Roots of a Quadratic Equations can be identified by:
>
>   The roots can be figured out by: 
>     $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{d}}{2a},$$ 
>     where
>     $$d=b^2-4ac.$$
> - When the equation has equal roots, then $d=b^2-4ac=0$.
> - That means $d=(b-c)^2-4(a-b)(c-a)=0$

Comment: What is $(b-c)^2 + 4bc$?

Comment: So have you tried working with your expression for $d$?

Comment: Yes, I tried to evaluate the $d$, It was (not completely evaluated) $$d= (b-c)^2-4(a-b)(c-a)=0$$ Is it right? And after this I am not able to understand that how to proceed now. Can you help?

Comment: Expand $(-2a+b+c)^2$ . Do you see some similarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the two roots are equal the discriminant must be equal to $0$.

$$(b-c)^2-4(a-b)(c-a)=(a-b+c-a)^2-4(a-b)(c-a)=\{a-b-(c-a)\}^2=(2a-b-c)^2=0 \iff 2a-b-c=0$$

---

Alternatively, solving for $x,$ we get $$x=\frac{-(b-c)\pm\sqrt{(b-c)^2-4(a-b)(c-a)}}{2(a-b)}=\frac{c-b\pm(2a-b-c)}{2(a-b)}=\frac{c-a}{a-b}, 1$$ as $a-b\ne 0$ as $a=b$ would make the equation linear.

So, $$\frac{c-a}{a-b}=1\implies c-a=a-b\implies 2a=b+c$$

Answer (score 4):

The expression for $d$ factors as $(2a-b-c)^2$, so we must have $2a-b-c=0$.

The easiest way to see this is to let $x=a-b,y=c-a$ and note that $b-c=-x-y$: $d=(-x-y)^2-4xy=x^2+y^2+2xy-4xy=(x-y)^2$.

**Alternative solution**: Note that $(a-b)+(b-c)+(c-a)=0$, i.e. $x=1$ is a root of the equation. If both roots are equal, it means that the other root is also $1$, showing that $(a-b)x^2+(b-c)x+(c-a)=(a-b)(x-1)^2$.

Equating the constant term, we find: $c-a=a-b$, which means $2a=b+c$. (This can be done with the coefficient of $x$ too).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** $(b-c)^2=4(a-b)(c-a)$, so $a-b$ and $c-a$ are either both nonnegative or both nonpositive. In the former case, put $x=a-b$ and $y=c-a$; in the latter case, put $x=-(a-b)$ and $y=-(c-a)$. Now the [A.M. $\ge$ G.M.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality says that
$$
\frac{x+y}2\ge\sqrt{xy},\ \text{ i.e. } (x+y)^2\ge4xy
$$
for $x,y\ge0$, and equality holds if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get the answer. Can you clarify what's A.M. and G.M.